# Can I indicate a regular expression requirement for a parameter value using Swagger?

Tags: swagger

In my REST API, one of the submitted parameter values must be a code following the regex:

`/[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}/`

Is there any way, besides putting it in the `description` property of the parameter, for me to indicate that the value is not valid if it does not match my regular expression?

I was not able to find any mention of regex's in the Swagger doc, except as a way to identify Patterned Fields (which is not what I want to do).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a field named [pattern](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object) in your api's parameters if is not a body or in your scheme definitions for properties, it use standard ECMA 262 : (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.3.3)

**[UPDATE Jul. 2019]**

OpenAPI 3 spec -
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! The syntax turned out to be: `pattern: ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}$`. No delimiters (such as / or ') are used/allowed, according to the YAML Editor, anyway.